# Django forms(not ModelForms): pre-populate checkbox data from model onto forms

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am trying using django forms and not model forms. While trying to populate data for edit I keep getting keyError (u 'manager'). This does not appear if I remove assignment of a field 'choices'. Choice is a many to many field on my model. to make it less confusing I will paste my model, forms and view.

**#model.py**

```
class Choices(models.Model):
choices = models.CharField(max_length=70)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.choices

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser)
    about_me = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choices, blank=True)
```

**#forms.py**

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (
        ('like to cook', 'like to cook'),
        ('like only to eat', 'like only to eat')
    )

    about_me = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=60,required=False)
    choices =forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=False)
```

**#views.py**

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = UserProfileForm(initial={'about_me':userprofile.about_me,
                                     'country':userprofile.country,
                                     'choices': userprofile.choices})
    return render(request, 'u_profiles/edit_pro.html', {'form':form})
```

now when I assign the initial value of selected choices I get the keyerror. I would like to know the correct way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Erm, seeing as this is a form with the same fields as the model, and pre-populated with model data, why *isn't* it a ModelForm?

Comment: But if you're getting an error, you should post it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Django forms provides more flexibility hence why I have used Forms.  The only error I get is a KeyError . Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
u'manager'
Exception Location: C:\Python27\projects\production\foodmunching\fm\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py in __call__, line 886

Comment: ModelForms offer *precisely* the same amount of flexibility, since they are subclasses of non-model forms, but never mind. That error doesn't seem to be coming from the form, but you'll need to post the whole traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Here is the complete traceback http://dpaste.com/37S7TZ4

Comment: I think you need to use a ModelMultipleChoice field. You're trying to pass a queryset of objects to the choices field on the form. Also it's user userprofile.choices.all()

Comment: @Roge It worked! userprofile.choices.all() was all I needed to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I took your suggestion and also tried ModelForm. Thanks